# Airflow Helm Chart Worker Node Error - CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, helm3

I am using official Helm chart for airflow. Every Pod works properly **except Worker node**.

Even in that worker node, 2 of the containers (git-sync and worker-log-groomer) works fine.

The error happened in the 3rd container (worker) with CrashLoopBackOff. Exit code status as 137 OOMkilled.

In my openshift, memory usage is showing to be at 70%.

Although this error comes because of memory leak. This doesn't happen to be the case for this one. Please help, I have been going on in this one for a week now.

**Kubectl describe pod airflow-worker-0** ->

```
worker:
    Container ID:  <>
    Image:         <>
    Image ID:     <>
    Port:          <>
    Host Port:     <>
    Args:
      bash
      -c
      exec \
      airflow celery worker
    State:          Running
      Started:      <>
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      <>
      Finished:     <>
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  3
    Limits:
      ephemeral-storage:  30G
      memory:             1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                50m
      ephemeral-storage:  100M
      memory:             409Mi
    Environment:
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID:                        0
      AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY:               <>                     Optional: false
    Mounts:
      <>
  git-sync:
    Container ID:   <>
    Image:          <>
    Image ID:       <>
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      <>
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      ephemeral-storage:  30G
      memory:             1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                50m
      ephemeral-storage:  100M
      memory:             409Mi
    Environment:
      GIT_SYNC_REV:                HEAD
    Mounts:
      <>
  worker-log-groomer:
    Container ID:  <>
    Image:         <>
    Image ID:      <>
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      bash
      /clean-logs
    State:          Running
      Started:      <>
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      ephemeral-storage:  30G
      memory:             1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                50m
      ephemeral-storage:  100M
      memory:             409Mi
    Environment:
      AIRFLOW__LOG_RETENTION_DAYS:  5
    Mounts:
      <>
```

I am pretty much sure you know the answer. Read all your articles on airflow. Thank you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376561/marc-lamberti

Comment: Have you also checked if the node is not overcommited? The sum of memory limits of all pods scheduled on the node can be higher than the node capacity and can exhaust the memory in the node. You can view it the same way as for the pod: ``kubectl describe node <insert-node-name-here>``.

Comment: Yes. It was actually under limit. The problem was other way around. In helm chart, there is resource limit mentioned. We need to increase it.

Comment: OOM means Out Of Memory - Check resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues occurs due to placing a **limit** in "**resources**" under helm chart - values.yaml in any of the pods.

By **default** it is -

```
resources: {}
```

but this causes an issue as pods can access unlimited memory as required.

By changing it to -

```
resources:
   limits:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 2Gi
   requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 512Mi
```

It makes the pod clear on how much it can access and request.
This solved my issue.